# Handling relative URLs in a locally-saved HTML file

Tags: python, html, url, web-scraping, relative-path

When `urllib2` is used to store to disk the contents of a page like [this](https://huddlebuy.workable.com/jobs/194756) thus:

```
url = 'https://huddlebuy.workable.com/jobs/194756'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
with open('spec.html', 'w') as spec:
    print >>spec, content
```

When spec.thml is opened in a browser, we can see that the URLs behind links such as:

[image]

.. go correctly to their underling links (http://www.perkbox.co.uk/, in this case). Relative URLs though, such as `/jobs/194756/candidates/new`, that of the Apply button:

[image]

... point to a location on disk, which obviously won't exist:

```
file:///jobs/194756/candidates/new
```

Is there a known way of avoiding this, without manually reconstructing the full URL (base URL + relative URL) and then doing a find/replace in the source before saving?

Comment: No, unless you reconstruct it after you retrieve the file.

Comment: Maybe adding a `base` element?